# I want to have page curl Animation while navigating from a view controller to another in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewanimation

I am having two view controller. A button on first view controller and tableview on another view controller. I want that when submit button is pressed view controller one will perform page curl up animation and then navigation take place.

I have tried using UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut it is working but when I write code for navigating to another view controller animation is not visible.
Else animation is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking into `UINavigationControllerDelegate's` method described [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uinavigationcontrollerdelegate/1621846-navigationcontroller?language=objc). You have to make an animator that conforms to `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` protocol. Then in the mentioned method check for the type of operation that is about to happen (`pop`, `push`) and apply the animation. It works just fine for me. I apologize for not providing code snippets, but you should be able to handle this based on the description.